# Встать "с колен" или "с коленей"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, грамматика

"*Встать с колен*" или "*встать с коленей*", как правильно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вопрос совсем не такой простой.

**"Встать с колен"** устоявшееся выражение, закрепившее старую форму. 
Обычно в такой форме используется только в переносном смысле. Разумеется, при использовании в прямом смысле допустима (как минимум) форма "встать с коленей". Форма "встать с колен" ни одним общеупотребительным словарем не фиксируется как нормативная **для всех случаев**, только в закрепленных сочетаниях.

http://radio7.podfm.ru/utro_v_gorode/50/
(аудиматериал)

Там такая мысль, что в закрепленных формах ("встать с колен", "одежда до колен") форма "колен" предпочтительна. Но в свободных - *только* "коленей". Однако, если второй случай (одежда) вопросов не вызывает, то первый, очевидно, вне переносного значения вполне может быть и "свободным сочетанием". "Встать" легко заменяется на "подняться", "вскочить" с коленей и т.д.

В нацкорпусе есть немало примеров использования в современном (и не только) языке этой формы именно в прямом значении.
http://search2.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%F1+%EA%EE%EB%E5%ED%E5%E9

Совершенно неупотребима форма "встать с колен", если речь идет о чужих коленях, на которых встающий ранее сидел (ребенок, например).

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54118/discussion-on-answer-by-morkovkin------).

Answer (score 4):

**Встать с колен или встать с коленей?**

Попробуем заглянуть в Нацкорпус:  **с коленей ― 60 примеров, с колен ― 760 примеров.**

Конечно, надо учитывать, что колено ― это (1) сустав или (2) часть ноги, но вот что интересно: персонажи книг **в самом прямом, не переносном  смысле** запросто встают с колен, стряхивают пыль с колен, роняют с колен салфетки, а собачки спрыгивают с колен (то есть с ног). Кстати, Грамота.ру  приводит выражение "встать с колен" в качестве нормативного.

Так что пока приходится говорить о том, что **употребляются обе формы (с колен и с коленей), причем преимущество явно за первым вариантом.**

**Примеры**

Тут комнату с этим самым диваном огласил дикий рёв Никанора Ивановича, вскочившего **с колен**: [М. А. Булгаков. Мастер и Маргарита, часть 1 (1929-1940)]

Оба клиента, не сговариваясь, прекратили жевать и молча встали, уронив **с колен** салфетки. [Дина Рубина. Белая голубка Кордовы (2008-2009)]

― Бабка совсем из ума выжила, ― весело жаловался вернувшийся Лёха, отряхивая **с колен** пыль. [Захар Прилепин. Верочка (2011)]

Пес сладко зевнул, потянулся всем телом, а потом и спрыгнул **с колен** Марии, цокнув коготками по гранитному полу. [Вацлав Михальский. Прощеное воскресенье // Октябрь, 2009]

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

**Как поссорились академические словари с современными писателями**

**Цитата:** "Везде формы "колен" вне устойчивых сочетаний признаются устаревшими".

Академики-то  признают их устаревшими,  а писатели пишут, корректоры проверяют, издатели издают, а читатели читают, и всё это происходит вне академического контроля: словари словарями, а писатели писателями. Ну давайте из 760 примеров добавим для убедительности ещё два:

Младший лейтенант Растягаев рылся в пыльных связках камышей, стараясь подняться **с колен.**..[**Виктор Астафьев**. Трофейная пушка // «Знамя», 2001].  Она спихнула кота **с колен** и встала. [**Людмила Петрушевская.** Город Света // «Октябрь», 2003]

**Но надо же  как-то всё это объяснить.** Дело в том, что устарела форма мн. числа "колена", отнесенная к человеку, вернее, стала использоваться в других областях (техника, музыка), а вот **Р.п. с нулевым окончанием устаревать никак "не желает"** и в силу своей краткости продолжает использоваться в нашем экономном языке (с колен, до колен). У этой формы (Р.п., нулевое окончание) вообще особые привилегии: к примеру, даже в счетном обороте "пять человек" она применяется, хотя сущ. "человек" вообще не имеет форм мн. числа.